# Dynamically modify number of columns in view, responsive layout

Tags: views, theming

I'm using one of the [AdaptiveThemes](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme&ei=9-fEUaK7LKHtiwLKjoHIAQ&usg=AFQjCNHfiRWCIP_5SuOD1EYE3rgyvBszDA&sig2=vdfm0FYBETfuhe-vnBjpug&bvm=bv.48293060,d.cGE) for a site I'm working on. For the sake of simplicity, we'll say it's a site for set of webseries. On the pages for the episodes, I'd like to have a view that displays thumbnails for each of the other episodes in the series. The view will ideally be setup like Hulu. For example, [here](http://hulu.com/family-guy), each of the episodes is listed in a slideshow list.

[image: Family Guy screenshot]

Since the site is responsive, I need to have the number of items displayed change with the size of the window. So, full size might show 4 thumbs, and as the view port gets smaller, it might change to 3 or 2 thumbs at a time. How can I achieve this?

Bonus points if you can give me a hint for scrolling through the list like the hulu site, too. Would that just be an implementation of [Views Slideshow](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views_slideshow-7.x-3.0.tar.gz)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicked on this from the DA active feed, but just spotted it is very old. Hope this is of help to others anyway.

---

You don't need a table, or dynamic changing of columns for this effect.

If I understand correctly, you are just creating a responsive carousel.

There are many out there, but I can recommend [Flexslider 2](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/carousel-min-max.html), and it comes with a hand [Drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider) too.

Should take you all of 5 min to get working.

Comment: I always seem to forget to update issues that I've opened in the past, but this is actually the solution that I ended up using!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the Hulu link, I'm not in the US, so I can't comment on the slideshow aspect.

I have used Display Suite to create my own layouts and Panels to access the responsive layouts within Adaptive Theme (AT Commerce) because Display Suite layouts are not responsive. I enabled only the core Panels module, trying to do the same with Panels got messy and Display Suite allows you to draw in fields from various sources.

There is a great series of tutorials on using Display Suite here: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7E361A55994F1648

You can also use Flexslider to make your images responsive

Answer (score 0):

I have recently installed https://drupal.org/project/footable . Demos can bee seen at http://fooplugins.com/footable-demos/ .

In short it enables you to set columns to appear or disappear depending on the width of the viewport. I think this is what you are trying to achieve.

There are two other modules worth looking at drupal.org/project/responsive_tables and drupal.org/sandbox/minorOffense/1793630 . Both of these seem promising but are somewhat immature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jcarousel module, patched with responsive support, to accomplish what you're looking for.

https://github.com/jmtorres/drupal-jcarousel/tree/develop

The original patch is in the jcarousel issue queue on drupal.org

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Views Fluid Grid](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_fluid_grid) to do exactly this.